# The passive that begins with 'It is thought' and past tense

Tags: passive-voice

Today doing some English grammar exercises I stumbled upon the two examples in *The passive* section:

> It is believed that the children had been hiding for two weeks.
>
> It was thought that the book had been destroyed.

The thing that puzzles me much is the usage of Past Perfect in the first sentence

> had been hiding

and, probably, in the second sentence

> had been destroyed

I had been searching over the Internet for several hours without any comprehensive answer found.

Would anyone please give a reference to the rule that explains the usage of Past Perfect in constructions like that?

The other related case is the following:

> The athlete was alleged to have cheated
>
> I'm sorry for what I said. I was trying to be funny. It was supposed to be a joke
>
> The book was thought to have been destroyed

Why can't I say respectively the following:

> The athlete was alleged **to cheat**
>
> It was supposed **to have been** a joke
>
> The book was thought **to be** destroyed

I'm able to easily find the rules on more simple constructions like *It is thought that ... + Present Indefinite / Present Perfect* but no comprehensive sources on similar but + Past Perfect

The book with exercises is highly recognizable btw but it doesn't give the answer

Thanks

Comment: 'It is believed that the children had been hiding for two weeks before the rebels finally found and captured them. They are believed to be safe and well, though a ransom demand is expected.' Here, the past perfect may be used to set the (assumed) hiding period at a time prior to their being found. // Have you actually Googled for examples of the alternatives you ask about?

Comment: Edwin, I tried to search for similar examples but without any luck. The book gives only the short versions of sentences (that I provided in the post) without any expansion that would more justify the usage of Past Perfect. Those short versions given in the book totally confused me.

Comment: As an example, Googling "was supposed to have been" turns up [this Grammar Exchange article](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/4051027123?r=4051027123) as the first hit. (Marilyn, rather than Kafkaesque in his/her second article, is the one to listen to.)

Comment: Edwin, thanks, but the link you pointed out doesn't give the answer on the usage of Past Perfect (without any expansion of the sentence) that confused me in the first place. It answers to the second part of my question here though

Comment: _Any_ use of the past perfect needs context (whether textual or situational). 'Hello, I'm John.  I hadn't been to one of these meetings  before.' doesn't make sense. But 'I felt rather uncomfortable, afraid I'd do the wrong thing.  I hadn't been to one of these meetings  before.' makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect is used to situate something in the distant past, i.e. in the past, prior to something else that happened in the past.  Your two example sentences are incomplete.  Here's what a complete version might look like:

> It is believed that the children had been hiding for two weeks when they were discovered in the cabin in the woods.
>
> It was thought that the book had been destroyed, prior to its surprise discovery.

---

> The athlete was alleged to be a liar

would work, but your sentence isn't right.  (You might hear it in informal speech, though.)

> It was supposed to have been a joke

This is fine.  You could also say

> It was supposed to be a joke

which means the same as "It was intended to be a joke."

> The book was thought to have the author's autograph in the inscription

would work, but the way you wrote it does not work.

Comment: Thanks. For me (being the non-native speaker) the difference between 'The athlete was alleged to be a liar' and 'The athlete was alleged to cheat' is very subtle. Could you please expand on why the latter is grammatically incorrect? Are 'The athlete was alleged to be cheating' and '..to have been cheating' also both incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You should realize that "to" is infinitive so in a sentence like: he was supposed to have been here - at the time the person wasn't but they were supposed to be - you are considering that the moment the action happened it was present time (he is supposed to be there).

Now, after the fact, you can only reflect on the action. So, the passive will be built with the infinitive of the perfect - to have + participle - in order to understand the connection.

Other examples:

- They were believed to have done us a huge favor (people believed they did it, and maybe we now have the means because of that favor).
- She is thought to have made the changes (people think she made the changes - we see the consequences of those changes now).

These are my own thoughts on the matter - I'm an English teacher and have done lots of studying throughout the years. Most grammar books only teach you separate subjects - either future perfect or passive with perfect. By combining both ideas you start realizing such connections. I hope to have helped!